# Objective-C: Coding for various iOS versions

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uivisualeffectview

I was wondering whether it is possible / how it is possible to code a class so it can be run on different iOS versions in Objective-C. For example the VisualEffectView is only available in iOS8 and after. Is it possible to declare a VisualEffectView if iOS >= 8 and UIView if not? If so can this be done within a header file?

I want to create an alert box to appear on top of a view controller when a save completes or error occurs. Depending on the iOS version it would be nice if a fancy blurry view is used or just a flat UIView.

Comment: What language are you programming in? It makes a big difference.

Comment: You need to read the [SDK Compatibility Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: @matt The OP mentioned "a header file" so I'm assuming Objective-C.

Comment: Stop saying "thanks".

Comment: @dgee4: could be worse.

Answer (score 1):

In an `if` statement, use `NSClassFromString`. You'll discover immediately that UIVisualEffectView doesn't exist when it returns `nil`, and thus you can take one branch if it exists and another if it doesn't:

```
if (!NSClassFromString(@"UIVisualEffectView")) {
    // ... use UIView ...
} else {
    // ... use UIViewVisualEffectView ... {
}
```

Comment: And for a more extensive list of conditional coding techniques for backwards compatibility, see my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch09.html#_device_architecture_and_conditional_code

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 5 you can the following syntax.

```
if ([UIVisualEffectView class]) {
    // Create and use a UIVisualEffectView
}
```

This will occasionally bite you, `NSMapTable` is available in iOS versions prior to iOS 6, but was only "officially" available in iOS 6. When attempting to use it in iOS 5 there was some sporadic undocumented behavior.

Comment: Won't this crash on an iOS 7 device because it doesn't have the UIVisualEffectView class?

Comment: Nope, using this syntax is safe to check for class availability in iOS 5 and above.

Answer (score 0):

As many have suggested, you can use the `NSClassFromString` function to find out at run time if the OS version has the class. If it doesn't (that is iOS 7 devices) and you still want live blurring, I'd recommend [LiveFrost](https://github.com/radi/LiveFrost).